# Calculate difference between two times on different dates in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have 4 cells:

- cell `A1` contains `16/8/2013` (this is date of entrance)
- cell `A2` contains `15:30` (this is time of entrance)
- cell `A3` contains `19/8/2013` (this is date of leave)
- cell `A4` contains `10:00` (this is time of leave)

What's the function I have to write in another cell so I get the time difference in hours between entrance and leave? This cell must appears like this: `66:30`.

Comment: Is there in Excel function to convert date and time to UNIX timestamp?

Comment: I dont know ): .....i just want 66:30 to appear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't need to be complicated. If A1 and A3 have real dates (if you can format them to "General" and they show as a number, then they are real dates), then you can do a simple addition formula

=(A3+A4)-(A1+A2)

and format the result with custom format `[h]:mm`

[image]